# Is there a way to pass JavaScript data to a PHP script without using Cookies or a POST request?

Tags: javascript, php, data-extraction

Well the title pretty much sums it up. I really have no idea where to start. I don't have any code to share at this point in time


If it helps, the same data is also being piped through a WebSocket server, maybe we could read the WebSocket stream with PHP?

Comment: There are PHP libraries for WebSockets.

Comment: If not POST, then maybe a GET, PUT or DELETE request? And/or any of the above, but using AJAX. Cookies are only transmitted as part of some sort of HTTP request, so that isn't really comparable - it's one way of putting the data within the request, but there are other ways too. Or yeah you could connect to the websocket server as a client, using PHP, although it's not clear how practical that would be in your scenario, you didn't really give that much context. Or you could have a PHP websocket server and send the same stream to that, maybe. Again, unsure due to lack of context. See [ask].

Comment: Hey @ADyson, you're right, I didn't include much in my question. Basically, I have a chat server that I need this for. The server currently polls a database whenever it gets a websocket message, but that's really slow and it gets laggy at times; what I want to do is:

on initial load, get db content;
as websocket messages come in, display them on screen;
when I receive a websocket message via PHP, insert the message to the db.

It seems as though using a php WebSocket client is the most logical thing to do in this situation, but if you have any other ideas please let me know!

Comment: So the chat server is not written in PHP? I'm not quite clear what direction all these socket messages are going, currently. Anyway you should add all clarifications to your question via the "edit" button, rather than lengthy comments :-).

Comment: Please clarify why a [POST (or PUT)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)  is not an option.